# python basic for loop/list comprehension

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

Say I have:

```
list=[('mike', 22.0), ('john', 33.0)]
```

I want to print a list of just the numbers, smallest to largest. I tried doing this:

```
for s in list:
    print(sorted(s[1]))
```

But it said 'int object is not iterable'?

If i do this, it works ( output is: [22,33])

```
print (sorted(s[1] for s in list))
```

How does the 2nd one work and what's the difference between the 1st and 2nd attempt? Hard time understanding the list comprehension technique.

BTW, the final goal is to print the NAME of the person will the lowest mark. But I'm trying to understand this part first before I associate the name with the mark. Dict would make it so much easier to assign key-values though

Comment: Type in `s[1]` and see what you get. Then type in `[s[1] for s in list]` and see what you get. Then see if it makes more sense.

Comment: Why don't use a `dict` here?

Comment: Don't name your list list, it will override the list function in python.

Comment: @RobertB How do i print just s[1] without the for s in list... s is not defined

Comment: @KevinGuan I'm trying to learn list comprehension, Dict would be easier though =p

Comment: @Angular And don't use `list` as a variable name, this will disabled `list()` built-in function.

Comment: @KevinGuan K true, but it doesn't matter for this example though right?

Comment: @Angular I know what's your question, let me post an answer.

Comment: @Angular I meant inside the loop. You could put `print(s[1])`. So that you can see what is going on. Python is interpreted and allows introspection. You need to learn out how dig into the data structures yourself and figure out how things work on your own. It is the perfect language for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
for s in list:
    print(sorted(s[1]))
```

You're trying to sort an `int`. The `sorted` function requires an `iterable` (for example, a list). Hence your error. This is noticeable since:

```
for s in list:
    print(s[1])
```

prints:

```
22.0
33.0
```

On the other hand, when you do: `Sorted(s[1] for s in myList)`, you're sorting a list (actually you're sorting a generator, but there's a somewhat fine line). Try:

```
newList = [s[1] for s in myList]
newList
```

and you'll see that you're essentially sorting a list. Sorting a list makes sense, but sorting a single number doesn't. `Sorted` is a function that returns a sorted list. To illustrate the difference between generators and iterables (like lists, tuples and dicts), compare the last snippet to the below:

```
newGenerator = (s[1] for s in myList)
print(newGenerator) #probably won't give what you ever need
for item in newGenerator:
    print item  #this will iterate through the items in the generator and print them
```

I had assumed you wanted the group sorted, but someone else answered that already and got downvoted so I didn't add it. Here is how you would do that:

```
myList.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])
```

Then:

```
myList[0][0]
```

Will be the name of the lowest person.

In this case, `sort` is a method, which operates on myList and changes it. If you pass it the `key = lambda x: x[1]` argument, it will sort the list based on the position `1`. So, if your number was in a different position in your tuples you would use a different number there. `lambda` is just a way to make a function on the fly, in this case the function just grabs the `1` element (second element).

Comment: So what would be another way to sort the numbers into a list , smallest to biggest ( apart from the list comprehension i did).

Comment: Actually I'm sorry, your way is the way that I would recommend doing it:
`sorted(s[1] for s in myList)`

but I would again recommend using `myList` vs `list`, since `list` converts things to lists in Python :)

Comment: K i won't use list next time. But for the sake of this example, I still don't get how the 2nd way works and 1st one doesn't...

Comment: When you do `sorted(s[1] for s in myList)` it only sorts `s[1]` (the second item in your `tuples`). I'll attempt to elaborate...

Comment: Okay yeah but why doesn't my first attempt work? shouldn't it iterate and only print out s[1] which is the 2nd item in my tuples, and this sorted([s[1]) would sort it?

Comment: Because you can't sort a number :) When you do `for s in list` you are looking at each item in the list on each iteration of the for loop. At that point, s will look either like `('john', 33.0)` or `('mike', 22.0)`. So, on the first iteration, `s = ('john', 33.0)`, and `s[1] = 33.0`. Finally, sorted(33) doesn't make sense, because it's just a number.

Comment: OH that makes sense! can you explain the step by step of the 2nd method, just like you did with this!

Comment: Sure, I am happy to try, though it might be fewer steps. Do you mean your second method, sorted(s[1] for s in list) or the one i showed you myList.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])?

Comment: the sorted(s[1] for s in list) one!

I haven't learned about lambda yet=p

Comment: Well, sorted is really just a function. So, when you do `newList = sorted(s[1] for s in myList)` the `sorted` function does most of the work, and returns a sorted list. `sorted` can take a generator, or an iterable though. A generator can be thought of as an expression that produces items. Whereas an iterable already has the items. `sorted(myIterable)` will work, and so will `sorted(myGenerator)`. In your case, you pass a generator to `sorted`, but if you play with the sorted function more, (for instance, try `print sorted([3,2,1])`), you'll see it works on `generators` and `iterables`

Comment: Try exploring `xrange` vs `range` in python2 to learn more about generators and iterables. The first is a generator and the second is an iterable.

Comment: okay, but my question is, what does this part do : s[1] for s in list. Why is that different than for s in list:   print s[1]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91894/discussion-between-rofls-and-angular).

Answer (score 2):

Because a list comprehension will give a **generator** here, see:

```
>>> Mylist=[('john', 33.0),('mike', 22.0)]
>>> print(s[1] for s in Mylist)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fd4a005e0f8>
```

And however, `sorted()` can be use on an *iterable* like **list** or **generator**, and then convert it to a list.

For example, `range()` will give a **generator** on Python 3(if you're using Python 2, use `xrange()` instead):

```
>>> a = range(20)
>>> sorted(a)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

And about why does this list comprehension give a **generator**, I think you forgot `[]`:

```
>>> Mylist=[('john', 33.0),('mike', 22.0)]
>>> print(sorted([s[1] for s in Mylist]))
[22.0, 33.0]
>>> print(sorted(s[1] for s in Mylist))
[22.0, 33.0]
>>> print([s[1] for s in Mylist])
[33.0, 22.0]
>>> print(s[1] for s in Mylist)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f8ab881c6d0>
>>>
```

By the way, about your code without list comprehension:

```
>>> Mylist=[('john', 33.0),('mike', 22.0)]
>>> l = []

>>> for s in sorted(Mylist, key=lambda x:x[1]):
...     l.append(s[1])

>>> print(l)
[22.0, 33.0]
```

Comment: why does that generator error thing come? What does it mean?

Comment: @Angular That's not an error, just means that's a generator. And what is *generator* please see [the document](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

Comment: Actually in python2 `range` gives a list but maybe you're using python3.

Comment: `xrange` produces a generator in python2.

Comment: @rofls Thanks, I'm really using Python 3 and however I think OP is also using Python 3 :P